# How to set Table/TableRow/TabelCell width by percent in code behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

How do I set width with percent in code behind? The only option I can think of is taking the parent width and calculate by percent.i.e. `TableRow.Width =  Table.Width.Value * 25/100` (set table row with width equals to 25% of the table width). However, eventually, how do I set the table width in percent? Without the table width, the child controls cannot use its parent widths to calculate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Will this not work?  Although I'm not entirely sure why you'd want a table row to be 25% of an overall table's width

```
TableRow.Width = new Unit("25%")
```

Answer (score 5):

.Net wrappers for html components dose not include "width" parameter( including the [HtmlTableRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ). and for those containing the "width" property, a .toString() is needed on the given solution.

an other easy approach would be using inline CSS styles ( first line is the answer rest is just a usage sample which I used to test the solution ) :

```
  c.Style.Add("width", "25% !important");
  c.Style.Add("border-color", "Red");
  c.Style.Add("border-style", "solid");
  c.Style.Add("border-width", "1px");
```

where c is the element