# Dynamically Adjust Table Cell Width

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically adding the rows and columns to a Table, but i am unable to adjust the first column's width.. i tried all possible combinations of  "Unit" (new Unit(300, Unit Type.Point) ) - but no joy.  It always shows the column-width to length of the data in that column,  but i wanted it to be fixed.  what's wrong here please.

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(); 
TableCell tc = new TableCell(); 
tc = new TableCell(); 
tc.ID = "tcResource"; 
tc.Text = "Resource_Name"; 
Unit uWidth = new Unit(300, UnitType.Point); 
tc.Width = uWidth; 
tr.Cells.Add(tc); 
for (i = 1; i <= 365; i++) 
{ 
  tc = new TableCell(); 
  tc.ID = "tc" + i.ToString(); 
  tc.Text = dtStart.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM") ; 
  dtRange[i - 1] = dtStart.AddDays(i ); 
  tr.Cells.Add(tc); 
} 
tHoliday.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Comment: It will be good if you add your code to original question instead of pasting it in comment.

Comment: "Duplicate": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258735/how-to-set-table-tablerow-tabelcell-width-by-percent-in-code-behind-in-asp-net

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Unit width = new Unit(30, UnitType.Pixel);
TableCell cell = new TableCell();

cell.Width = width;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adjusting the columns width with a CSS style, not by doing it server side. Put this in a CSS file:

```
td.tcResouce{ width:300px }
```

and add a link in your ASP.Net page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/file.css">
```

Comment: I want to do it on server side(dynamically)