# How do I make my table cells the same width but still responsive?

Tags: html-table

How can I keep my table responsive but have each row keep the 3 cells and if 2 or 1 of the cells don't have info in I want all 3 cells to have the same width?

Does this make any sense?

http://pubshed.co.uk/drinks/alcoholic-drinks/cocktails/

```
<table style="width: 100%;">

<tbody>

<tr>

<td style="text-align: center;">AK-47

<img class="alignnone wp-image-281 size-full" src="http://pubshed.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/ak47-e1460028266118.jpg" alt="AK47" width="90" height="150" /></td>

<td style="text-align: center;">Americano


<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-271" src="http://pubshed.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/americano-150x150.jpg" alt="americano" width="150" height="150" /></td>

<td></td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: do you want to merge cells if they don't contain any info?

Comment: no don't want to merge cells.just want 3 cells the same width

Comment: You should set the widths as [percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258735/how-to-set-table-tablerow-tabelcell-width-by-percent-in-code-behind-in-asp-net). If you show us a sample of your code it would be more  helpful for us to understand you inquiry.

Comment: i have added the code above

Comment: Thanks. Try adding `width:"33.3333%"` in every table cell.